# MApView not displaying in android using google api v2

Tags: android-intent, android-webview, google-maps-android-api-2

I have made an application in android for google map using mapView api2,I have tried the following code.map is runnig completely but i want it when snippet is clicked ,then particular "url" should be loaded in secondActivity's webview. my code is  as below:

**Main.java**

```
package com.example.mapviewdemo;

import java.security.PublicKey;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap.OnInfoWindowClickListener;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.UiSettings;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptorFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {
    private GoogleMap map;
    WebView wv;
private String a ;
private String b ;
//public String ah="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ahmedabad";
//public String br="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baroda";
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        map = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
        setUpMap();
        if (map != null) {
         Marker Ahmedabad = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(
                    new LatLng(Double.parseDouble("23.03957"), Double
                            .parseDouble("72.56600"))).title("Ahmedabad"));
            Marker Baroda = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                    .position(
                            new LatLng(Double.parseDouble("22.30731"), Double
                                    .parseDouble("73.18110")))
                    .title("Baroda")
                    .snippet("Baroda")
                    .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                            .fromResource(R.drawable.pin_blue)));

            // Move the camera instantly to hamburg with a zoom of 15.
            map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(
                    new LatLng(Double.parseDouble("23.03957"), Double
                            .parseDouble("72.56600")), 15));

            // Zoom in, animating the camera.
            map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(10), 2000, null);
             a =Ahmedabad.getTitle();
             b = Baroda.getTitle();
        }
    }
    private void setUpMap() {

        UiSettings setting = map.getUiSettings();
        setting.setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true);
        map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        map.setTrafficEnabled(true);

        map.setOnMarkerClickListener(new OnMarkerClickListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if(arg0.getTitle().equals(a)){
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Ahmedabad", 0).show();
                }
                else
                {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Baroda", 0).show();
                }

                return false;
            }
        });
        map.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(new OnInfoWindowClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if(arg0.getTitle().equals(a)){
                Intent i =new  Intent(getApplicationContext(),SecondActivity.class);
                i.putExtra("ahm", a);
                startActivity(i);
                }
                else{
                Intent i =new Intent(getApplicationContext(),SecondActivity.class);
                i.putExtra("brd", b);
                startActivity(i);
                }
            //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Check",0).show();    
            }
        });

    }

}
```

**second.java**

```
package com.example.mapviewdemo;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.webkit.WebView;

public class SecondActivity extends Activity {
WebView v;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);
    v=(WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView1);
    Bundle b =getIntent().getExtras();
    b.getString("ahm");
    b.getString("brd");


    }



}
```

**main.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />



</RelativeLayout>
```

**second.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".SecondActivity" >

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While using google maps android api v2, the click on any part of the infowindow is taken as an infowindow click event and you cannot specifically distingusigh whether snippet or any other part was clicked. Your click listener code seems correct. When you detect which marker's infowindow was clicked, you can do any of the below 2 approaches:

1, Directly call a webview by passing the required url as parameter :

```
 Uri uri = Uri.parse("http://www.yourlocationspecificuri.com");
 Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
 startActivity(intent);
```

2, Call your 2nd activity as you are doing now and then after reading the intent to know the marker that was clicked launch the webview with the required url :

```
v.loadUrl("http://www.yourlocationspecificuri.com");
```